# Can any one resolve this exception in the below Thrift program?

Tags: c++

I am new to Thrift.
I am trying to create a table ("sample") in Hbase using the following Thrift program on ubuntu 10.10 and can anyone tell me whether this is correct or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <poll.h>

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <protocol/TBinaryProtocol.h>
#include <transport/TSocket.h>
#include <transport/TTransportUtils.h>

#include "Hbase.h"

using namespace apache::thrift;
using namespace apache::thrift::protocol;
using namespace apache::thrift::transport;
using namespace apache::hadoop::hbase::thrift;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> socket(new TSocket("localhost", 60010));
    boost::shared_ptr<TTransport> transport(new TBufferedTransport(socket));
    boost::shared_ptr<TProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
    HbaseClient client1(protocol);
    try
    {
        transport->open();
        string tableName("Sample");
        vector<ColumnDescriptor> columns;
        columns.push_back(ColumnDescriptor());
        columns.back().name = "cf:";
        columns.back().maxVersions = 10;
        columns.push_back(ColumnDescriptor());
        columns.back().name = "test";
        try {   
            client1.createTable(tableName, columns);
        } catch (const AlreadyExists &ae) {
            std::cerr << "WARN: " << ae.message << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const TException &tx) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << tx.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But i am getting the following exception at this place `client1.createTable(tableName, columns);`

```
ERROR: No more data to read.
```

Please help in resolving this.

Comment: At first glance, are you sure that the connection is working correctly ? Seems to me like a connectivity issue.

Comment: I checked the communication its working fine but not able to create table through above program

Answer (score 1):

Got it, 
Need to start thrift server on hbase by `.<hbaseinstallationpath>/bin/hbase thrift -threadpool start`